# How to get Apache httpd response time with ssl enabled

Tags: ssl, apache, mod-ssl

My httpd.conf has

`LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %T/%D" combined`

I get the following information logged in access_log

`10.xxx.xxx.xxx - uid [10/Dec/2012:21:52:20 -0800] "GET /file.ext HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0" 0/2105`

I am particularly looking for the time-taken-to-server-the-request in microsec.

When I try the same LogFormat with mod_ssl enabled I am not getting the same desired information in the access-log.

`httpd-ssl.conf has ' LogFormat "%U %T/%D" timediff '`

But I see only the below information in ssl_access_log

`10.xxx.xxx.xxx - uid [10/Dec/2012:21:46:00 -0800] "GET /file.ext HTTP/1.1" 200 2742`

Could experts help me here?